# Decoding an encrypted HTML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted page source of an HTML file. I am searching for a decoding trick to decrypt a page containing Facebook interface UI. It is in the following post [decrypted facebook UI](http://www.0measure.com/2011/08/facebook-wallscript-user-interface.html) page. The demo page of that post is encrypted. Is there any possible way to decrypt it?

Answer (score 2):

That's not really encrypted, just encoded. The answer's actually right there in the source. You need to run all that stuff between the innermost quotes through the Javascript [unescape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions) function. Here's a handy page for it: [Online Unescape Decoder and Encoder](http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/unescape.html).